# Testing AWS AppSync Resolver Error functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

I have been following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/test-debug-resolvers-js.html to write unit tests for my AppSync functions and resolvers.  Everything works well until I try to test the error states.  My code is as follows:

code.js

```
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils'

/**
 * Request a single item with `id` from the attached DynamoDB table datasource
 * @param ctx the context object holds contextual information about the function invocation.
 */
export function request(ctx) {
  const { args: { id } } = ctx
  return { 
    operation: 'GetItem',
    key: util.dynamodb.toMapValues({ id })
  }
}

/**
 * Returns the result directly
 * @param ctx the context object holds contextual information about the function invocation.
 */
export function response(ctx) {
  const { error, result } = ctx;
  if (error) {
    return util.appendError(error.message, error.type, result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

context.json

```
{
  "arguments": {
    "id": "1234",
    "description": "test"
  },
  "source": {},
  "result": {
    "id": "1234"
  },
  "request": {},
  "error": {
    "type": "ERROR",
    "message": "Error Happened"
  },
  "prev": {}
}
```

code.test.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const client = new AWS.AppSync({ region: 'us-east-2' })
const runtime = {name:'APPSYNC_JS',runtimeVersion:'1.0.0')

test('Error handling', async () => {
  const code = fs.readFileSync('./code.js', 'utf8')
  const context = fs.readFileSync('./context.json', 'utf8')
  const contextJSON = JSON.parse(context)
  
  const response = await client.evaluateCode({ code, context, runtime, function: 'request' }).promise()
  const result = JSON.parse(response.evaluationResult)

  expect(result).not.toEqual("")
})
```

I'm expecting the response to come back with the result and errors block but instead get an empty string as the "evaluated response function", I think this is due to `appendError` returning `void` but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it so it returns the result and error blocks.